# Две кнопки на весь экран

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Хочу получить страницу с таблицей на весь экран, из двух ячеек, каждая из которых полностью будет занята большой кнопкой. Однако 100% заполнение получается лишь по ширине. Вот код страницы:

```
<head>
    <title>ПДД</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="index.php"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
                    <button type="button" name="name">Правила дорожного движения категорий АВ</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="index.php"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
                    <button type="button" name="name">Правила дорожного движения категорий СД</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Вот код таблицы стилей:

```
body { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
button { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
table { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
input { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
    <title>ПДД</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
                <form method="post" action="index.php"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
                    <button type="button" name="name">Правила дорожного движения категорий АВ</button>
                </form>
    </div>
    <div>
                <form method="post" action="index.php"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
                    <button type="button" name="name">Правила дорожного движения категорий СД</button>
                </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

СSS

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
button {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
div{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
form {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает